# Sorting a list in Python while respecting the relative order position of duplicate sort keys?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list to while respecting the original sorting order and keeping its "logical integrity" – e.g. if an element is on the most right it will move to the most left when sorting. The background here is to make LDAP's sorting compatible with x509 certificates.

An element's `distinguishedName` in LDAP looks as follows: `CN=John Doe,OU=Marketing,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=loc`, but certificates require their names to be saved in the following format `DC=loc,DC=contoso,OU=Users,OU=Marketing,CN=John Doe`.

Because I want to offer some error redundancy when users add normal x509 certificates I came up with a simple sort to normalize user inputs e.g. `OU=Tech,ST=Berlin,C=DE,CN=test.com` becomes `C=DE,ST=Berlin,OU=Tech,CN=test.com`; however I'm having some issues getting the desired results when parsing LDAP `distinguishedName`s – it's not keeping the *original ordering logic* of the `DC`s and `OU`s.

My code looks like this:

```py
SUBJECT_FIELDS = [
    "DC",
    "C",
    "ST",
    "L",
    "O",
    "OU",
    "CN",
    "emailAddress",
]

def sort_name(subject):
    return sorted(subject, key=lambda e: SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(e[0]))
>>> subject = [('CN', 'John Doe'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc')] 
>>> sort_name(subject)
[('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
# should be [('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]

>>> subject = [('CN', 'John Doe'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc')]
>>> sort_name(subject)
[('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
# should be [('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]

>>> subject = [('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'ad'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
>>> sort_name(subject)
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'ad'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
# works as intended

>>> subject = [('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc')] 
>>> sort_name(subject)
[('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
# probably never going to happen that somebody screws an OU up like this, but should be:
# [('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
```

So the issue is that sorted does not "reverse" multiple occurrences of the same sorting-`key`, thus screwing up the original *logical integrity* of the name.

I have already tried extending the `sorted` function with a weighted ordering based on how far on start or end of the list the subject field is.

```py
def sort_name(subject):
    half_index = len(subject) // 2
    relative_index = lambda x: len(subject) - subject.index(x) \
        if subject.index(x)+1 > half_index \
        else subject.index(x) - len(subject)
    sorted_fields = sorted(subject, key=lambda e: (SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(e[0]), relative_index(e)))
    return sorted(subject, key=lambda e: (SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(e[0]), relative_index(e)))
```

But unfortunately that seems to involve a lot more unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def sort_func(s):
    return [
        t
        for _, t in sorted(
            enumerate(s),
            key=lambda k: (SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(k[1][0]), -k[0]),
        )
    ]


subject = [
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "loc"),
]

print(sort_func(subject))
```

Prints:

```
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
```

---

Other `subject`s:

```
subject = [
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
    ("OU", "Marketing"),
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("OU", "OtherUnit"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "loc"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))

subject = [
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "loc"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))

subject = [
    ("DC", "ad"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "loc"),
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))
```

Prints:

```py
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'ad'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
```

---

EDIT 2:

```py
SUBJECT_FIELDS = [
    "DC",
    "C",
    "ST",
    "L",
    "O",
    "OU",
    "CN",
    "emailAddress",
]


def sort_func(s):
    if SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(s[0][0]) > SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(s[-1][0]):
        return sorted(s[::-1], key=lambda k: SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(k[0]))
    return sorted(s, key=lambda k: SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(k[0]))


subject = [
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "loc"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))

subject = [
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
    ("OU", "Marketing"),
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("OU", "OtherUnit"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "loc"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))

subject = [
    ("DC", "loc"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "ad"),
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))

subject = [
    ("OU", "Users"),
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("DC", "loc"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))

subject = [
    ("DC", "loc"),
    ("DC", "contoso"),
    ("CN", "John Doe"),
    ("OU", "Users"),
]
print(sort_func(subject))
```

Prints:

```
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'ad'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]
```

Comment: Can't say I quite understand it yet, but: Wizard. Works as expected!

Comment: However when sorting the output of `sort_func` again with `sort_func` it actually goes back to mixed up results. `subject = [('CN', 'John Doe'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc')]; sorted_subject = sort_func(subject); sorted_subject2 = sort_func(sorted_subject)` results in `[('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]`

Comment: @schlumpfpirat I cannot replicate it, see my edit.

Comment: You're not using the parameter `s` passed to the function (`enumerate(subject)`), which probably accidentally leads to you referencing the globally defined variable `subject` instead.

Comment: @schlumpfpirat Ops, that's true... I look at it :)

Comment: hehe cheers – that's why it also passed my initial attempts flawlessly too. :p

Comment: @schlumpfpirat The problem is, how do you want to distinguish `[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]` from `[('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc'), ('OU', 'Marketing'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('OU', 'OtherUnit'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]`? In your test case you had `[('DC', 'ad'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc'), ('OU', 'Users'), ('CN', 'John Doe')]`. You need to have an condition that if first is `loc` then don't sort.

Comment: ah I see. I edited the example; sorry that was quite misleading. You cannot distinguish it. You simply have to assume, that whatever is on the most left or most right part of the list is the start. So it really should either be `[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'),...` or `..., ('DC', 'contoso'), ('DC', 'loc')]`. Everything else is a user error beyond repair.

Comment: @schlumpfpirat See my new edit.

Comment: What if we have e.g. `[('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('CN', 'John Doe'), ('OU', 'Users')]`?

Comment: @schlumpfpirat Yeah, I've just updated it, just `return sorted(s, key=lambda k: SUBJECT_FIELDS.index(k[0]))`

Comment: It still mixes it up a bit when omitting e.g. `[('CN', 'John Doe'), ('DC', 'loc'), ('DC', 'contoso'), ('OU', 'Users')]`, but I guess that can be considered as too big of a user error to consider.

Comment: Well I've said it before and I'll say it again – this time for real: Wizard. Thanks man! Was really going crazy over this for 3-4 hours... which probably speaks more to my ability as a programmer in general than the problem itself.